# Getting setVisibility to Work in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar, visibility

**I can't get the ProgressBar to become invisible. I have tried the following based on other StackOverFlow Q&As, without success:**

- adding clearAnimation() method
- calling the progressbar with a getter-method from the activity
- calling the progressbar with a getter-method from the fragment
- checking if the findViewByID returns null (it doesn't)
- running the method completely in the activity instead of the fragment
- moving the progressbar higher or lower in the XML
- calling it with a handler

Thanks a ton in advance for any help. Spent 2 whole days with this thing

**FRAGMENT:**

```
public class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {


public ProgressBar mProgressBar;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle onStavedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_activity_main, container, false);

    mProgressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_load_candidates);
    mProgressBar.clearAnimation();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return rootView;
}
```

**XML:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_candidates"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_main_bottom_nav"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_load_candidates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorKLMBlue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drop_shadow_elevation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow_elevation_upwards"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_main_bottom_nav" />

    <com.xx.android.xxx.ui.bottomnav.BottomNavBar
        android:id="@+id/view_main_bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_main_bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: why not invisible it in xml ?

Comment: I'm going to put it in an if-statement after. To hide it if there is an internet connection. Just wanted to simplify the code here

Comment: do you want to hide progressbar when internet is active?

Comment: have you tried `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: @AndroDevil yes exactly.

Comment: @Ali Ahmed Yes I've tried that, doesn't work either.

Comment: any error you have in `Logcat`?

Comment: @AliAhmed yeah, sometimes I get the "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: YOu should check your are referencing `Progress bar` to correct `id` in your xml. It seems you're giving progress bar wrong id. *(id of progress bar from any other xml)*

Comment: @AliAhmed I checked that now but it's not the case. When I run it as the code above there are no error messages in the Logcat

Comment: @TheFluffyTRex are you using webview ?

Comment: @AndroDevil no, not using a webview